# How to check whether an Object is String or String Array in java?

Tags: java

A method is returning a `Object` or `Object[]` of type `String` but if I am casting with `String[]`, it is giving class cast exception when it contains single string. How can i resolve this?

Is there any way to check whether it contains `String` or `String[]`?

Answer (score 26):

Sure, use the [`instanceof` operator](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.20.2):

```
if (x instanceof String) {
  ...
}

if (x instanceof String[]) {
  ...
}
```

etc. It's not ideal to have to do this, mind you... is there any way you could redesign your API to avoid this?

Comment: Due to object orientation concerns. The very fact of using `instanceof` is equivalent, in this case, to saying "my method could have returned `String[]` in all cases (as a `String` can always be put in a `String[1]`), but as I was not smart enough to do it, i prefered to return anything and let you cope with it."

Comment: The easiest way to change the API is to always return a String[], with in stead of the String a String[] of size 1.

Answer (score 7):

Rewrite the method to always return `String[]`, even when there's only a single one.

Better yet, have it return `List<String>` and use [`Collections.singletonList()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList(T)) for the single-element case.